# selector xml for checkbox works on KitKat but not on JB

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a newbie to android and was trying out changing look and feel of checkbox. I used the selector xml(btn_check.xml) from android android-sdk\platforms\android-#\data\res\drawable. Here is a snip -

```
<!-- Enabled states -->


<item android:state_checked="false"
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/check_mark" />
<item android:state_checked="true"
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/check_mark_green" />


<!-- Disabled states --> 

<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/check_mark" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/check_mark_green" />
```

In the activity xml i am using this as follows  -

```
<...>
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:button="@drawable/btn_check"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
    android:text="CheckBox" />
```

The PROBLEM is that this code works on the emulator for kitkat for it just crashes - saying resource not found on JellyBean. The logcat mentions that "btn_check" resource is not found. The btn_check.xml is in the drawable folder alongwith other png files.

Been trying to get this to run on JellyBean since yesterday afternoon, but no luck!! Any help would be appreciated.

Wondering how to insure against such platform differences!!

Comment: Forgot to mention that the emulator is of Api 16. thanks.

Comment: Try to clean your project.

Comment: Cleaned multiple times. Also uninstalled pervious copy on the emulator. Check the apk file if it contains the xml or not. But still no luck!!